# Need to fetch the column names(field names) along with the values in raw sql query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

**views.py**

```
def view(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    with open('D:\Project-Management-Tools\Project-Management-Tools\query.sql','r') as inserts:
        query = inserts.read()
        cursor.execute(query)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
    return Response(row)
```

**SQL query**

```
SELECT PUBLIC."Users".ID,
            EMPLOYEE_NAME,
            BILLABLE_AND_NON_BILLABLE,
            PUBLIC."Job".PROJECT_ID,
            PUBLIC."Timelog".CLIENT_ID,date,PUBLIC."Timelog".HOURS
        FROM PUBLIC."Users"
        JOIN PUBLIC."Job" ON PUBLIC."Users".ID = PUBLIC."Job".USER_ID
        JOIN PUBLIC."Timelog" ON PUBLIC."Timelog".JOB_ID = PUBLIC."Job".ID
```

I have tried a raw query by inserting a sql file in cursor function. However I am getting the values alone as a response and I need to get the fields name along with the values in the response. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One simplest way is to fetch the column names by using this query`SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name='accounts'`
and then further you can query the values as separate query and create a mapping between two.

Comment: can you please elaborate it more i couldn't able to get it. I have added my sql query above please check and help to get this sorted. Thanks in advance!!